# How to put an application on startup to system tray

Tags: windows-xp

Is there some way that I can put an application to system tray on startup. This application is a proprietry application and I cannot access the code, it has to just minimise and sit on the system tray.. How can I do that.

Comment: No, you can't do this. You can start it minimized, but you can't place an icon in the **taskbar notification area** ([it's not and has never been called the "system tray"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/10/54831.aspx)).

Comment: @Cody Gray: You have no idea how often it *is* called the "system tray". (Yes, I know the name is *technically* incorrect, but... meh, this is not the best place for that.)

Comment: When you minimize said application, does it automatically go to the notification area, or is this a feature you want to add to the application?

Comment: Check this question: https://superuser.com/q/1087391/485660

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what said Cody Gray, there is a bunch of tools that can do that. Just search online about "minimize startup tray" and you will find several matches.

One free tool that I used for a while is `Tray minimizer` from the [Net Tools pack](http://mabsoft.com/nettools.htm), but it need manual placing to tray via a menu, and getting a whole tools package for a single utility may not be worth if you do not need net utilities.

A second that fullfill your request is `TrayIt!`. Its website is now defunct but there are still copies availables, e.g. on the [CommentCaMarche.net](http://www.commentcamarche.net/download/telecharger-34078337-trayit) community.