# Minimize app WhatsApp in system tray / notification area

Tags: windows, windows-10, notification-area, whatsapp

I am looking for a way to minimize `WhatsApp` (the official Windows app) in the system tray.

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Try [How can I move icon from taskbar to system tray in windows 7?](http://superuser.com/a/1060876) (Windows 7 answer, but may work in Windows 10 - not tested).

Comment: Thank you, but not functional :/

Comment: Look at Sebastian Ax's answer, it works.

Comment: Almost 3 years Fastforward and this has still not been fixed. Most windows apps would insist on not closing and will remain in taskbar, is it too difficult for WA engineers to do this ? Windows 8. Dont wanna install another app just for this. Even the lack of needed settings like making font smaller is annoying.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I have modified [the RBTray app](http://rbtray.sourceforge.net/) to work with the WhatsApp desktop client.

[Download WhatsappTray here](https://github.com/D4koon/WhatsappTray/releases)

**Important: DON'T start the application with admin rights unless WhatsApp is also running with admin rights!**
Otherwise, it will not work because of communication problems between the two applications.

Tested with Win10 64bit (64-bit WhatsApp client).

Comment: This works great!

Comment: B2GraphiX should mark this as the answer, this is the only working solution so far to send whatsapp to tray, thank you !

Comment: great thx .......

Comment: Thanks for this. Currently its working only on click minimize in whatsapp desktop. Not working with minimize from taskbar. Also could you please make it minimize to systray on closing desktop version.?

Comment: wow, I just found you already did that on right click menu in systray, great.

Comment: Tried it on windows 10. Didn't work at all.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you.  You should also mention there is also a setting that will also keep it running in the system tray when you close the app (typically called "minimize on close" this was the function that I was looking for when I searched)

Comment: Hi, RBTray doesn't work with most of the app right now. Cloud you develop this to work with other apps as well?

Comment: fyi, there is another approach to this of wrapping the whatsapp web page vs the desktop app: https://github.com/D4koon/WhatsappTray2 ... i did a spin on this myself before i realized: https://github.com/Beej126/WhatsAppWebWpf

Answer (score 4):

Use this program: http://rbtray.sourceforge.net/.

I tested with WhatsApp and worked fine!

[image]

---

**Updated: April 2020**

Use this [RBTray](https://github.com/benbuck/rbtray) which is a fork of Original RBTray and It works fine.

**Download**

- [64-bit binaries](https://github.com/benbuck/rbtray/tree/master/x64)
- [32-bit binaries](https://github.com/benbuck/rbtray/tree/master/x86)

<sup>Note: Download both .dll file and .exe file.</sup>

**Using**

To minimize a program to the system tray, you can use any of these methods:

- Right-click with the mouse on the program's minimize button.
- Hold the Shift key while Right-clicking on the program's title bar.
- Pressing Windows-Alt-Down on the keyboard (all at the same time).

Comment: Thanks, i try but if no good for windows 10 64Bit.

Comment: @B2GraphiX, I downloaded this program, it had 32Bit and 64Bit versions in the downloaded zipped file. I tried both of them on Windows 10 64Bit, they both work. Please give it another try. And make sure you RIGHT click the minimize button of any program you want to minimize. Hope this helps.

Comment: its not working with whatsapp however with other app its working

Comment: Not working with the latest Whatsapp updates (nov/dec 2016), but check out Sebastian Ax's answer for something that does.

Comment: NOT working with Whatsapp, actually not working with some windows, something to do with new way to make windows, except whatsapp, only battle.net app don't go to tray, also, from your picture, I see you have windows 7 ... **NOT WINDOWS 10** AS THE QUESTION IS !

Comment: The April 2020 update does work with the `Shift` + click method.